# Spring Boot inject properties from external file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Spring Boot application will be built as a war file and placed in Tomcat/webapps next to other applications. How to tell Spring to read properties file from Tomcat/conf/some.properties so that specific properties could later be injected in certain classes like:

```
@Value("${some.property.name}")
private String prop;
```

Answer (score 0):

You either load them with a env variable:

```
spring.config.import=file:./additional.properties,optional:file:/path/to/file/your_file.properties
```

or programmatically:

```
public MyPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties = 
      new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    properties.setLocation(new FileSystemResource("/path/to/file/your_file.properties"));
    properties.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(false);
    return properties;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `@PropertySource("file:/path/to/myfile.properties")` on a `@Configuration` class

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Maven I will report an extract from the official documentation that you can find on [Maven documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html).

> To reference a property defined in an external file, all you need to do is add a reference to this external file in your pom.xml. First, let's create our external properties file and call it src/main/filters/filter.properties:

```
# filter.properties
my.filter.value=hello!
```

**pom.xml**

```
...
<build>
    <filters>
      <filter>src/main/filters/filter.properties</filter>
    </filters>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
    </resources>
  </build>
...
```

**application.properties:**

```
# application.properties
message=${my.filter.value}
```

From that point on you can inject the property as usual

Comment: 'How to tell Spring to read properties file from Tomcat/conf/some.properties' is very different from 'how to bake properties into the WAR at build time'